# main differences between each tree in a RF and CART best tree?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, random-forest, cart-analysis

Main differences between each tree in a RF and the best tree from CART?

Answer (score 0):

The main differences between trees in a Random Forest and the best tree from CART are :

- The training set of each tree in the RF is a subset of the main trainset (bootstrapping)
- At each node of a RF tree, a subset of feature is used to choose the best one for the split